# BlackBerry JavaScript support of keycodes/keypresses

Tags: javascript, blackberry, keycode

I'm new to dealing with BlackBerry devices. I'm currently running into a JavaScript issue on a 9700 and trapping keypress events and getting a proper keycode.

I have this javascript:

```
function numbersonly(e) {
    var key
    if(window.event) {
        key = window.event.keyCode; // IE
    }else{
        key = e.which; // Firefox
    }

    alert('keycode : ' + key);
```

}

And it's attached to an input field via an unobtrusive addEvent script.

On a standard desktop browser (Firefox and IE), it does what you'd think it does...pressing a key will show the keycode via the alert.

On a blackberry, however, pressing a key does one of two things:

- if the key presses is the numbers 1 through 9, nothing happens.
- if it's any other key, the keyCode is 'undefined'.

Any idea what's going on? I assume it's a limitation of the BlackBerry JavaScript support.

UPDATE:

Tested this on a 9800 Simulator as well, which is running OS6. Problem doesn't exist there. So this is either an issue with BlackBerry OS5 or BlackBerry's physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the *event* variable is set when you add an inline event handler.

Have you tried setting the event-handler from javascript. So something like

```
document.getElementById('mytextelement').onkeypress = keytest;
```

Comment: Would that be a BlackBerry centric issue? The above script works as-is in Firefox, for example.

Comment: @DA I don't think there is any specification that states the the _event_ variable must be set for inline event handlers. It work in IE because IE used to use window.event instead of passing the event object with the function. Firefox added the behaviour to be compatible with IE. I'm not sure if BB did the same.

Comment: Well...I'll try that. That said, the app we're working on does all JS as inline event handlers. Good or bad, that's likely the model I need to work in.

Comment: Well, I have that a shot to no avail. Exact same issue. I've updated the script above to hopefully give more info.

Answer (score 0):

Try using e.keyCode instead of e.which

Comment: Tried that as well. Same result. Stupid BlackBerry! ;)